# Heeeey Baatttty

Tags: knowledge, steganography

Oh no! The Joker is at it again, and this time, he has kidnapped somebody VERY CLOSE to Batman. The Joker sent a letter, which read,

> [image]
> P.S. That's a fiiiine lady. Heee hee!

(Transcribed)

> Hey Batty,
>
> Ha, ha, ha! I've got you on the ropes this time. I've taken someone veeeery special from you. You want to get him/her back? Too bad. I've only sent this letter just to gloat over your loss.
>
> Ugh, but the damn Riddler keeps on telling me I HAVE TO put in some kind of riddle or something to help Batty out. Fine. Fine. FINE! I'm not putting a riddle, because I'm not the DAMN Riddler, but I'm the Joker. Hee hee hee! Ha ha ha! I love MURDERING PEOPLE OVER AND OVER AGAIN!!!! I'm already getting excited!
>
> Anyhow, your precious little friend is quite free, though he/she is... well gagged and bound. He/she also is inside a fire! But hey, there's water nearby!
>
> Bye bye,
> Joker
> P.S. (That's a fiiiiine lady)

Can you help the Caped Crusader rescue this person and bring Joker to justice?

Comment: By the way, there us nothing obscene or inappriate about this steganography (especially the PS).

Comment: Could you transcribe the image into text? My internet does have the capability to load images. If the image is as put, an image, then can you tell you what is going on inside of it?

Comment: I will transcribe the image.

Comment: You will, however, need the image, so I dont know how I could help you there

Comment: I don't need to use Steghide right

Comment: I cannot disclose that information, however, the text should be plenty

Comment: If I have to use steghide, then it's not allowed though, steghide cannot be the only way to answer the problem

Answer (score 6):

It's perhaps worth noting that:

> A 5 bit LSB decode gives: [image] 
>  
>  So it looks like Superman (Or in this case perhaps supergirl, from "Fine lady") is the victim? Unless an inverted logo is another character... I only know that it stands for "Resurrection" in Kryptonian

Comment: It is ressurection! We have a DC fan here.

Comment: resurrection matches with "I love MURDERING PEOPLE OVER AND OVER AGAIN"

Comment: Frustratingly, there is an obscure DC character very linked to resurrection, but it's the location I'm now struggling with... "Inside" a fire, and near water... Inside is an odd way to put it, implying they aren't actually ON fire.

Comment: Ooooh you guys are getting it! I give you a hint: Joker decided to operate OUTSIDE of Gotham City. Also, its not Ressurection man, if thats who you are thinking about

Comment: It also implies a very SPECIFIC location

Answer (score 5):

Is the person trapped in

> The Statue of Liberty?

.

> - "fiiiiine lady": Lady Liberty
> - "quite free": a symbol of freedom
> - "gagged and bound": The poem at the base of the statue notes its "silent lips"
> - "inside a fire": Perhaps trapped inside the torch? The poem at the base of the statue even calls it the "imprisoned lightning"
> - "there's water nearby": the statue is on an island

.

> Another fun fact: There is a DC character named [Lady Liberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Liberty_(comics))

edit: about who the person could be:

> The Statue of Liberty's poem was written by Emma Lazarus. This reminds me of the Lazarus Pit, so maybe the Joker has kidnapped Talia al Ghul? The Lazarus Pit is used for resurrection as well, like the resurrection symbol found in the LSB decoder.

Comment: Nice job! The Joker has taken the hostage to the Statue of Liberty!

Comment: I did NOT know that there was a DC character named Lady Liberty (lol) :)

Comment: @North I added a theory of who could be the captive as well!

Comment: Sorry, the theory captive is incorrect! Though that was a very creative guess.